# unable to create new route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a controller method `search_same_director`. The link code from `show.html.haml`:

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director','/movies/search_same_director', :director=>@movie.director
```

I have added the following line to `routes.rb`

```
match '/movies/search_same_director'=>'movies#search_same_director'
```

But the link routes the request to the show action. How can I correct this?

Comment: Do you have the `&gt;` in your code?

Comment: thats how it is displayed when i use the code option in the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set up the route, so use the rails path in the view:

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', search_same_director_path(@movies.director), :director=>@movie.director
```

And since you're passing `director` to the action, change the match statement in `routes.rb`:

```
match '/movies/search_same_director/:director'=>'movies#search_same_director'
```

Also, make sure the `match` statement is above the `resources :movies` statement in the routes file.